# .net core app being built is being detected as virus by Symantec endpoint protection

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am working on developing a few small .net core apps in a corporate environment. However, whenever the app is built (simple app), it is being detected by Symantec Endpoint Protection as a heuristic virus.

I think the build may just need to be signed or have information so it doesn't get false positives. Has anyone else encountered this and know how to resolve?

Thanks
Stuart

Comment: I had a similar experience. For me though, only the 32bit build was flagged and the 64bit version worked correctly.